# SSIS Excel connection manager: files only readable with wrong Excel version selected

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, connection

Since I had to reinstall my development PC anew, I'm now facing some issues when loading my saved SSIS projects or creating new ones in Visual Studio 2012.

When trying to use a Excel connection for .xls files created as 97-2003 format, I receive the following error:

---

*Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'*

---

After some experimentation if found out that .xlsx files where working properly and the sheets of the .xls files can be read when I set ECM to MS Excel 2007.

Thing is, I'm not the only one updating these procedures and on my backup notebook they still work as intended with Excel version 3 (97-2003), same as the files. So when I update a procedure to Excel version 4 for it to work on the PC, it's invalid for all others.

Would appreciate any help to fix this.

***Setup information (Same basic setup for PC and Notebook):***

Win10 x64, Office 2013 x86, SQL Server Data Tools 2012 (x86),
On PC: Also installed Access Database Engine for Office 2010, 2007

Comment: Look at this link there are some useful advice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/excel-connection-manager

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by either Windows update **[KB4041678](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4041678/windows-7-update-kb4041678)** (Security only update) OR **[KB4041681](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4041681/windows-7-update-kb4041681)** (Monthly Rollup) In our case it was KB4041687. We had a number of SSIS packages fail because of this update, once the below work around was implemented the SSIS packages are back up and running.

**Known issues for these updates include:**

"Installing this update may cause applications based on the Microsoft JET Database Engine (Microsoft Access 2007 and older or non-Microsoft applications) to fail when creating or opening Microsoft Excel .xls files. The error message is, “Unexpected error from external database driver (1). (Microsoft JET Database Engine)"."

Microsoft is working on a resolution and will provide an update in an upcoming release.

The **Recommended work around** is to download and install "[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistribute](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)"

As per Install Instructions ("To use this download"), Once the Access Database Engine is installed you will need to update the Excel Connection Manager(s) ConnectionString Provider from Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

For example, Before

Provider=**Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0**;Data Source=D:\Scatch\test.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";

After

Provider=**Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0**;Data Source=D:\Scatch\test.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";